# C# SSH.NET continuous Read

Tags: c#, ssh

I'm trying to set up a SSH connection to a remote device and want to see what happens on the other side.

When I use

```
var device = client.RunCommand(Command);
var output = device.Result;
```

I can see what happens if I write things like ls -a but what I want is a way to always read what the device says just like a PuTTY window or CMD window

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `CreateShell` or `CreateShellStream` method, not `RunCommand`, and continuosly read the stream, to emulate what an SSH client like PuTTY does.